# Retrieving component from Embeddedschemafield error in .NET

Tags: tridion

I've been working on a .NET C# TBB to retrieve fields from a schema, which in turns parses through every embedded field. I use Razor Mediator in my templates to output JSON. I'm very new to C# and .NET and I'm therefore using and referring code my colleagues wrote in other templates.The goal of the TBB is to retrieve, after publish, the exact url of an image within one of these embedded fields, and push it back to the package as plain text.

This eventually seemed to work, up until I changed one of the fields of the embedded schema's to a multimedialink. As soon as I set the Embeddedschemafields to loop through, template builder serves an error with the o so descriptive

```
Operation is not supported on a new item or on a null URI.
```

I have no clue why this is happening, since the code actually *worked* . That's why I believe changing one of the embedded schema's fields could be the culprit, but the error occurs even before looking this particular field up. my code stops at retrieving the component from the embeddedschemafield:

```
CM.Schema schema = (engine.GetObject(comp.GetAsSource().GetValue("ID")) as CM.Component).Schema;
ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(schema);
foreach (ItemField field in fields)
{
   _log.Info("top level: " + field.Name);
   if (field is EmbeddedSchemaField)
    {

     CM.Component c = (CM.Component)engine.GetObject(package.GetByName(Package.ComponentName));
      _log.Info(" c = " + c + " content:  " + c.Content + " schema:  " + c.Schema);
      ItemFields content = new ItemFields(c.Content, c.Schema);
      EmbeddedSchemaField embeddedFields = (EmbeddedSchemaField)content[field.Name]; //boom

      MultimediaLinkField mmValue = null;

      ItemFields currentFields = null;

      foreach (ItemFields embeddedField in embeddedFields.Values)
      {
```

Anyone have an idea?

This is the log I got from template builder:

```
GetComponentImageUrl: top level: name
GetComponentImageUrl: top level: division
GetComponentImageUrl: top level: theme
GetComponentImageUrl: top level: product
GetComponentImageUrl: field.Name = Embeddedschemafield
GetComponentImageUrl:  c = Component tcm:11-1963 content:  System.Xml.XmlElement schema:  Schema tcm:11-1842-8
GetComponentImageUrl:  c. Content = System.Xml.XmlElement
Engine: Error in Engine.Transform
Engine: Error in Engine.Transform
Operation is not supported on a new item or on a null URI.
  at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetTcmUri(String uri)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetObject(String uri)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetObject(XmlElement linkElement)
```

Comment: Have you tried checking that the field exists before trying to cast it to an EmbeddedSchemaField? Like this - if (content.Contains(field.Name)) { // do something }

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, and a very curious thing occured. I put the if-loop right after the c loginfo, and added an log.info right after the if loop and added an else message if the field wasn't named. the template broke down right before that, apparantly, because non of the messages actually fired other than the _log.Info("c...") - and right now I believe ' ItemFields content = new ItemFields(c.Content, c.Schema);' might be the spanner in the works. Would explain the 'new item' message, too.

Comment: Interesting. Are you able to debug the template in Visual Studio? The logging suggests not, but I believe it would give greater clarity if you could.

Comment: The template itself _should_ be fine. I'm currently completely cleaning up the code to be able to generate anything other than an error. Within Template builder I turned on extra logging, and it returned a log which I'll append to the original question.

Comment: I probably should have been a little more specific - I meant the TBB. It's possible to attach Visual Studio's debugger to the TemplateDebugHost process so you can step through your code and a clearer picture of what's failing, where, when, and why.

Comment: Can you confirm that you've tried checking that the ItemFields object "content" is not null, and that is contains the field you're looking for? If you're not able to debug the TBB in VS then I would probably add more logging (pretty much adding a message between every line of real code).

Comment: I've logged my nads off, and turns out that the problem was indeed null/new item all along. I've set a xml field from text to multimedia, and gone and tested the page without adding any binaries to the new fields i described. Turns out having non-mandatory fields but actually referring to them without them being filled isn't something tridion particularly likes. My thanks to you @Jeremy, for helping out. I'll ask around if anyone around the office already added the debug like you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

```cs
CM.Schema schema = (engine.GetObject(comp.GetAsSource().GetValue("ID")) as CM.Component).Schema;
ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(schema);
foreach (ItemField field in fields)
{
  _log.Info("top level: " + field.Name);
  if (field is EmbeddedSchemaField)
  {
    CM.Component c = (CM.Component)engine.GetObject(package.GetByName(Package.ComponentName));
    _log.Info(" c = " + c + " content:  " + c.Content + " schema:  " + c.Schema);
    ItemFields content = new ItemFields(c.Content, c.Schema);

    if (content != null && content.Contains(field.Name)) {
      EmbeddedSchemaField embeddedFields = (EmbeddedSchemaField)content[field.Name]; //boom

      MultimediaLinkField mmValue = null;

      ItemFields currentFields = null;

      foreach (ItemFields embeddedField in embeddedFields.Values)
      {
```

Notice the added check that the ItemFields object is created, and that it contains the field you're looking for.